# Android custom class dependency for aidl

Tags: java, android, gradle, aidl

So I have the following project structure:

```
.
├── Central
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── build.gradle
│   │   └── src
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── gradle.properties
│   └── settings.gradle
└── Client
    ├── app
    │   ├── build.gradle
    │   └── src
    ├── build.gradle
    ├── gradle.properties
    └── settings.gradle
```

In the Central app, I define a service and along with it an AIDL interface. In the AIDL, one of the functions returns a custom object (which extends Parcelable). In the Client app, I put the exact same AIDL file (under the same package in the `src/aidl` directory). I try to import the custom class by declaring a gradle dependency to the Central app.

Here is the Client's settings.gralde

```
rootProject.name='Client'
include ':app'

include ":Central"
project(":Central").projectDir = file('../Central/app')
```

The Client's app/build.gralde:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.Patel.Cli3n5"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation  project(path: ':Central', configuration: 'default')
}
```

And the aidl file (present in both apps):

```
package com.Patel.Central;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
parcelable Info;

interface MusicCentral {
     List<Info> getAllSongsInfo();
     Bitmap getSongImage(int songNum);
}
```

And note that the Info class is defined in the package `com.Patel.Central`.

When I try to build the Client app, I get the following error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
    @Override public java.util.List<com.Patel.Central.Info> getAllSongsInfo() throws android.os.RemoteException
```

In summary, the problem is that there is a custom class and I need to import from an app that is in another directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define both files

`Info.java`

and

`Info.aidl` seprate `aidl` file for Info.java

with same package name at both client and remote application.

means package should have

```
MusicCentral.aidl
Info.java
Info.aidl
```

in `com.Patel.Central` package.

Comment: Why would I need Info.aidl? Info is a class (implementing parcelable)? Also I am trying to import the class implementation through gradle dependencies. I prefer not to copy the implementation of the Info class.

Comment: Same contract will be shared by both client and remote that is set through aidl file.

Comment: Yes the contract is shared by both the client and the remote. But the client need the custom class implementation as a dependency.